# HIbernate and CMT

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, ejb

Lately I decided to implement in my project CMT transactions (jBoss5, Hibernate, jta postgres datasource).
Everything is working fine except Hibernate.initialize() in my entities.
It works in EJB beans but when trying to invoke initialize in entity getter I get "couldn't associate with session" exception. It worked just fine before implementing transactions.
Anyone got accros same problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after days browsing the internet I found what is the problem.
When u flag method as Supports transactions. It doesn't start them.
If you retrieve objects out of transaction they are out of session and therefore u cannot initialize their properties...

Answer (score 0):

From the following [reference page](http://www.hibernate.org/42.html) you may need to ensure the current properties are configured correctly for CMT

- set `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` to a lookup strategy for your Java EE container (see [here](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/configuration-j2ee.html) for a list of JTA transaction managers)
- set `hibernate.transaction.factory_class` to `org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory`

Comment: I wrote that everything works except Hibernate.initialize() and that only in entities.
I have already set hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class.
(I don't want to set transaction factory because Hibernate entity manager doesn't like that). Anyone idea what is the problem ?